# How can I use my docker DotNetCore app after running in a droplet?

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core

I've set out to run a aspdotnet application on my digital ocean droplet. I believe I've got pretty far:

- I have created a templated docker aspdotnet core web application in visual studio.
- I built and ran the docker image locally on my machine, verified it works.
- I pushed the image to the docker hub.
- I ssh'd into my droplet, installed docker, logged in with my docker user account and pulled the image from the docker hub.
- I started the image and it is currently running:

[image]

The problem is when I navigate to the IP address of my droplet I simply cannot seem to connect.

What am I doing wrong?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ImANovelSoWhat/ImANovelSoWhat.csproj", "ImANovelSoWhat/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ImANovelSoWhat/ImANovelSoWhat.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ImANovelSoWhat"
RUN dotnet build "ImANovelSoWhat.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ImANovelSoWhat.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ImANovelSoWhat.dll", "--server.urls", "http://+:80;https://+:443"]
```

[image]

Comment: May be your port 80 is occupied by another process try to expose application on different port by adding -p 5000:80 and check with 5000 port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to publish your ports. Append the `-p 80:80` to your docker run command. (Exposing a port doesn't make it available when you run a container. To do that, you need to publish your ports.)

`docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:80:80 yourimagename`

Comment: Sadly this didn't change anything

Comment: Can you post your docker ps commands output after my suggestion?

Comment: Also your Command column should display what is given on your ENTRYPOINT in Dockerfile, but yours has "bash" there.

Comment: Updated OP with image of the ps output. Looks like Command column is correct.

Comment: Please post the output of the command: `curl -v http://<yourIP> ` (don't forget, to redact your ip)

Comment: For me it works now (you forgot your ip on the connection refused image)

Comment: That's interesting. Doing `curl -v http://<droplet_ip>` is outputting me the index html file.
Still not connecting for me. I wonder why its working for you and not me.

Comment: nvm my browser was defaulting to https, when it needed to be http xd

Comment: Maybe you are getting redirected to https (because of hsts, but that would be wierd), try to open the url in incognito mode of your browser.

Comment: All works, thanks for sticking around with me :)